# C++ Windows forms function need to accept string value from the TextBox and then return the string value to the label

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

In Windows Forms I use 2 textBox. Information from the textBox1 have to become one of the parameters to function **encrypte()**, that accepts two `string` parameters and return **string** value.

```
std::string encrypte(std::string text, std::string key);
```

To convert string to String^ I use marshal_as, but marshal_as refers to old function template. I see the old version of my programm. If I don't use marshal_as there isn't that error.

Earliel I had "label2->Text = "fjff"" instead of "label2->Text = ENC". Works first one ("fjff"), that I had even deleted.

```
  private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

    System::String^ text;
    System::String^ key;
    if (checkBox1->Checked) {
        text = System::Convert::ToString(textBox1->Text);
        key = System::Convert::ToString(textBox3->Text);
        msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
        string key2 = context.marshal_as<std::string>(key);
        string text2 = context.marshal_as<std::string>(text);
        string enc = encrypte(text2, key2);
        String^ ENC = context.marshal_as<System::String^>(enc);
        label2->Text = ENC;
    }
}
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: What is the exact error you get when you use `marshal_as` ? Please [edit] your question and add it.

Comment: @wohlstad it isn't real error, just refers to old version of the project.

Comment: @wohlstad earlier I have the "label2->Text = "vff"", instead of "label2->Text = ENC" and works first one, that I had even deleted

Comment: The code you posted seems to be OK. I do not understand what is the actual problem you have. _"refers to old version of the project"_ - what does that mean ?

Comment: @wohlstad I mean that works old code, that I deleted. This one doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by _"This one doesn't work"_ ? If you don't get any compiler error, you should put a breakpoint and verify that the content of `key2` and `text2` is as you expect.

Comment: @wohlstad I rebuilt my projects. It works correct now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I rebuilt my project and it is solved the problem.